# Tesseract TessData fonts used for training

Tags: android, tesseract

I am using tesseract for OCR in an Android app. I am focusing on the Chinese language but I only need to recognise a few keywords so I was thinking of creating my .traineddata files using jTessBoxEditor. I wanted to know what fonts does the Chinese Traditional TessData file use? https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata

Alternatively, is there a way that I can edit the chi_tra.traineddata file so it only recognises a few keywords? The main reason I am doing this is because the file size is 63.4 MB and tesseract takes around 2 to 3 minutes before finishing. The accuracy is great but is slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `font_properties` file of all `tesseract` trained languages can be found  in [github](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/langdata/blob/master/font_properties). You may check the traditional chinese specific fonts supported from the list.

From `tesseract-ocr/langdata` folder [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/langdata) in github, you can check the `chi_tra.wordlist` inside `chi_tra` folder to find the words used for training.